# Draggable Background Js not working in ie8

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8, draggable

I'm using [Draggable Background Js](https://github.com/kentor/jquery-draggable-background) for dragging the background image but It's  not working in IE8, the console says

`Unable to get property 'match' of undefined or null reference`,

`File: draggable_background.js, Line: 63, Column: 15`.

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/uqcuqtxf/

What is the issue? how can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Um, the Github page you linked to for the Draggable Background library explicitly states that it is only compatible with IE9+.

Which means that you're not going to get it to work in IE8. It relies on browser features that IE8 simply doesn't have.

If you really need to support IE8, then you're going to need to achieve this effect some other way or with some other library.

Comment: It seems unlikely. It relies on the CSS `background-size` property which isn't supported by IE8. You could try [searching for a polyfill library](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=css+background-size+polyfill) to add the `background-size` feature to IE8; there are some out there, but I can't guarantee how well such a hack would work with the library you're using.